# Is it possible to upgrade an NFT instead of having to burn the previous and creating a new one?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, nft

I wanted to know if this was possible. For example, if I own 1 NFT of Charmander and I then "mint" an evolve, is there a way to turn the first Charmander into Charmeleon without creating a new NFT.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. You can make a transaction to ethereum to change the atribute of the nft like name 'Charmander' to 'Charmeleon' or other stuff.

Doing It is way cheaper than burn the nft and mint a new one (I dont knoww haven't test it but high chance it is).

Comment: I see thank you! But is it possible to change the image? I understand we can change the name and some data, but what about changing the actual image to now show a Charmeleon?

Comment: @sorrowlol https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/104166/updating-erc-721-tokenuri-after-its-already-minted?rq=1